# How to discover devices like Firetv, Airplay, Chromecast, Roku on a local network within a Flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, service-discovery, mdns

it's my first post here. Happy to be a part of a healthy community.
So I am working on a Flutter project which requires me to fire up discovery for devices such as **FireTV, Chromecast, Roku, Airplay, Samsung** on the tap of a single cast button, and then play media on the selected one.
Now I have spent days behind the research before posting it here.

- I have come across this discussion on GitHub -> https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18212
- Also, the TLDR would be this link -> https://github.com/terrabythia/flutter_chromecast_example
- Using this already for FireTV -> https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_fling

I have got FireTV nicely working even the media controls and tested, the problem starts with how do I join them all to be fired up in a single call, and yet get generic data back. Throughout my research, I have been bombarded with words like mDNS and Cast SDK's receiver. Also being new to network discovery, I am finding it difficult to get a proper direction. I am open to working on native solutions and maybe even building a plugin, but since this project has time constraints, I am really looking for ways I can implement this on an MVP level.

What I am looking for is how should one be going about to solve this kind of problem, or building a solution and get it working. Any help is highly appreciated, thanks.